# MSBuild: ReadLinesFromFile query

Tags: msbuild

I am using ReadLinesFromFile for reading multiple lines from a txt file and appending it to the path in sql.execute. The problem is its reading all the lines and appending them at once:

Text File Contents:

a.sql
b.sql

Sql.Execute ServerName="$(ServerName)" DatabaseName="CDRCntroller" path="..\DB\CDRController\BROKER\@(Prop1).

MSBuild is taking the path as : .....\BROKER\a.sql;b.sql

Any way I can use Prop1 as an array and refer the contents in the file one by one?

I tried using StringToItemList also but no luck :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this

Sql.Execute ServerName="$(ServerName)" DatabaseName="CDRCntroller" path="..\DB\CDRController\BROKER\%(Prop1.Identity)

The % tells Msbuild to repeat the task for each item. Identity is a Metadata containing the item itself.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank for the 'Identity' metadata bit - I was having a whale of a time finding this.  The MSDN documentation on all the metadata available for an Item does not seem that complete.

Comment: Well, you can find some stuff about metadata here in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use metadata notation instead. Like this :

```
Sql.Execute ServerName="$(ServerName)" DatabaseName="CDRCntroller" path="..\DB\CDRController\BROKER\%(Prop1.Identity)
```